# Does this go raytracing program follow best practices, and typical project layout?

Tags: beginner, image, go, graphics, raytracing

I'm working through learning Go, so as an exercise, I'm writing a simple raytracer. I'd like general feedback on the code style & architecture. Specific areas of concern:

- Is the project layout reasonable?
- Are my types and interfaces clear, and the right types/interfaces to be using?
- should the receiver of a function typically be named something like this, self, or other? is it important to be consistent with this across different source files?
- transformation.Inverse computes cofactors() twice, once through Det, and once for itself. avoiding this seems to come at the cost of duplicating Det's code inside Inverse. is there a clean way to avoid this?
- with Sphere & Spatial Object, the idea was, I'm going to implement multiple geographic primitives, that just differ in how intersections are calculated. They all have the common data components of Transform. I want InverseTransform cached on them, since it's expensive to calculate, at least in theory.

The project is currently about 500 lines of code, including tests, so I've abbreviated in places.

render_scene.go:

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/png"
    "log"
    "math"
    "os"
    "pathtrace/spatial_object"
    "pathtrace/transformation"
    "pathtrace/vector"
)

func find_first_hit(ray vector.Ray, scene []spatial_object.Hittable) (did_hit bool, intersection spatial_object.Intersection) {
    did_hit = false
    best_distance := math.Inf(1)
    for _, obj := range scene {
        this_hit, this_inter := obj.Hit(ray)
        if this_hit && this_inter.T < best_distance {
            best_distance = this_inter.T
            intersection = this_inter
            did_hit = true
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {

    scene := []spatial_object.Hittable{
        spatial_object.Sphere(spatial_object.New(transformation.Translation(vector.NewVector(0, 0, 0)))),
        spatial_object.Sphere(spatial_object.New(transformation.Translation(vector.NewVector(2.5, 0, 0)))),
        spatial_object.Sphere(spatial_object.New(transformation.Translation(vector.NewVector(-0.5, 0.5, 1)))),
    }

    //set up the view stuff
    size := image.Rect(0, 0, 640, 480)
    eye_pos := vector.NewPoint(0, 0, -4)
    eye_up := vector.NewVector(0, 1, 0)
    eye_right := vector.NewVector(1, 0, 0)
    eye_forward := vector.NewVector(0, 0, 1)
    view_angle := math.Pi / 2
    dist := 0.5
    h := dist * math.Tan(view_angle/2)
    w := h * float64(size.Max.X) / float64(size.Max.Y)

    img := image.NewNRGBA(size)
    background_color := color.NRGBA{0, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF}
    light_dir := vector.NewVector(0, 1, 0)

    for y := size.Min.Y; y < size.Max.Y; y++ {
        for x := size.Min.X; x < size.Max.X; x++ {
            up_component := eye_up.Multiply(h * (1.0 - (2.0 * float64(y) / float64(size.Max.Y))))
            right_component := eye_right.Multiply(w * ((2.0 * float64(x) / float64(size.Max.X)) - 1.0))
            forward_component := eye_forward.Multiply(dist)
            dir := forward_component.Add(up_component).Add(right_component)
            ray := vector.Ray{eye_pos, dir}

            did_hit, inter := find_first_hit(ray, scene)
            if did_hit {
                diffuse_intensity := light_dir.Dot(inter.Normal) / (light_dir.Magnitude() * inter.Normal.Magnitude())
                diffuse_intensity = math.Max(0, diffuse_intensity)
                shaded_green := color.NRGBA{0, uint8(255 * diffuse_intensity), 0, 0xFF}
                img.Set(x, y, shaded_green)
            } else {
                img.Set(x, y, background_color)
            }
        }
    }

    outfile, err := os.Create("test.png")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    png.Encode(outfile, img)
}
```

transformation/transformation.go

```
//a Transformation is a 4x4 matrix, which represents a linear transformation of a point
//in addition to some standard matrix operations, constructors from typical transformations such as Translation, Scale, Rotation, and Shear are provided.

package transformation

import "pathtrace/vector"

//hold the actual matrix in a 1-dimensional array, for efficiency.
type Transformation [4 * 4]float64

func Translation(t vector.Vector) Transformation {
    return Transformation{
        1, 0, 0, t[0],
        0, 1, 0, t[1],
        0, 0, 1, t[2],
        0, 0, 0, 1}
}

...

var Identity = Transformation {
    1,0,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,
    0,0,1,0,
    0,0,0,1}

//rotate by r[0] radians aronud x, then r[1] radians aronud y, then r[2] radians around z
//func Rotation (r vector.Vector) Transformation {
//todo
//}

func (self Transformation) Multiply(other Transformation) Transformation {
    //just writing out the multiplication inline.
    //this should whole thing really should be done in an existing library
    ...
}

func (self Transformation) MultiplyVec(vec vector.Vector) vector.Vector{
    return vector.Vector{
        self[ 0]*vec[0] + self[ 1]*vec[1] + self[ 2]*vec[2] + self[ 3]*vec[3],
        self[ 4]*vec[0] + self[ 5]*vec[1] + self[ 6]*vec[2] + self[ 7]*vec[3],
        self[ 8]*vec[0] + self[ 9]*vec[1] + self[10]*vec[2] + self[11]*vec[3],
        self[12]*vec[0] + self[13]*vec[1] + self[14]*vec[2] + self[15]*vec[3]}
}

//internal use. compute the cofactors of the matrix
//we return a list of float64 instead of a transform, because it's not really a transform
func (t Transformation) cofactors() [16]float64 {
    ...
}

func (t Transformation) Det() float64 {
    cf := t.cofactors()
    return t[0]*cf[0] + t[1]*cf[1] + t[2]*cf[2] + t[3]*cf[3]
}

func (t Transformation) Inverse() (result Transformation) {
    d := t.Det()
    cf := t.cofactors()
    for i, v := range cf {
        //result, transposed, is cofactor / determinite
        result[(i%4)*4+i/4] = v / d
    }
    return
}
```

transformation/transformation_test.go:

```
package transformation

import (
    "math"
    "testing"
)

func TestMultiply(t *testing.T) {
    a := Transformation{
        8, 7, 2, 1,
        9, 4, 33, 8,
        1, 5, 0, -2,
        7, 5, 4, 22}
    b := Transformation{
        18, 6, 66, 0,
        -3, -7, 8, 89,
        1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8}
    expected := Transformation{
        130, 9, 597, 639,
        223, 140, 781, 552,
        -7, -41, 92, 429,
        225, 147, 668, 637}

    if a.Multiply(b) != expected {
        t.Errorf("expected %v, but got %v\n", expected, a.Multiply(b))
    }
}

....
```

vector/vector.go

```
package vector

import "math"

//homogenous coordinates 4-tuple.
//a purely directional vector is {x,y,z,0}
//a point in space is {x,y,z,1}
//for now, we'll treat a Point exactly as if it's a vector
type Vector [4]float64

func NewVector(x, y, z float64) Vector {
    return Vector{x, y, z, 0}
}
func NewPoint(x, y, z float64) Vector {
    return Vector{x, y, z, 1}
}

type Ray struct {
    Position, Direction Vector
}

func (v Vector) MagnitudeSquared() float64 {
    return v.Dot(v)
}
...etc
func (r Ray) PositionAt(t float64) (position Vector) {
    return r.Position.Add(r.Direction.Multiply(t))
}
```

spatial_object/spatial_object.go:

```
package spatial_object

import (
    "math"
    "pathtrace/transformation"
    "pathtrace/vector"
)

type Hittable interface {
    Hit(vector.Ray) (did_hit bool, intersection Intersection)
}

type SpatialObject struct {
    Transform, InverseTransform transformation.Transformation
}

func New(transform transformation.Transformation) SpatialObject {
    inverse := transform.Inverse()
    return SpatialObject{transform, inverse}
}

type Sphere SpatialObject

type Intersection struct {
    T        float64
    Position vector.Vector
    Normal   vector.Vector
}

func (s Sphere) Hit(ray vector.Ray) (did_hit bool, intersection Intersection) {
    pos := s.InverseTransform.MultiplyVec(ray.Position)
    dir := s.InverseTransform.MultiplyVec(ray.Direction)
    transformed_ray := vector.Ray{pos, dir}
    //a transformed ray hits the generic sphere at time t if |position+dir*t|^2 = 1
    //this expands to |dir|^2*t^2 + 2*(position dot dir)*t + (|position+^2) - 1 = 0
    //which is a quadratic equation over t. we solve for f(t)=0.
    a := dir.MagnitudeSquared()
    b := pos.Dot(dir)
    c := pos.MagnitudeSquared() - 1
    discrim := math.Pow(b, 2) - a*c
    if discrim < 0 {
        return false, Intersection{}
    }
    //discrim / a must be positive, so t1 <= t2
    t1 := -b/a - math.Sqrt(discrim)/a
    t2 := -b/a + math.Sqrt(discrim)/a

    var hit_t float64
    if t1 >= 0 {
        hit_t = t1
    } else if t2 >= 0 {
        hit_t = t2
    } else {
        return false, Intersection{}
    }

    hit_point := ray.PositionAt(hit_t)
    hit_normal := transformed_ray.PositionAt(hit_t)
    hit_normal[3] = 0 //make it a vector
    return true, Intersection{hit_t, hit_point, hit_normal}
}
```

spatial_object/spatial_object_test.go not shown.